# Heat-bath algorithm of 2D XY model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, simulations, phase-transition, spin-models

Can anyone suggest any reference where the **heat-bath** algorithm for the **classical 2D XY** model has been discussed in detail. I have found references for the 3D Heisenberg model which can be exactly implemented as the probability distribution is integrable, which is not the case for the 2D XY model.